# How to get the derivative with StepMonitor?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, evaluation, options

I am trying to use StepMonitor inside of the NDSolveValue function for a complicated system of differential equations, but the simple example below shows my issue just fine.

I am trying to obtain values of the derivative during the process of solving the differential equation by using StepMonitor.

```
Reap[NDSolveValue[{y'[x] == -x, y[0] == 1}, y[x], {x, 0, 100},StepMonitor :> Sow[y'[x]]]]//Last
```

And I get as an output a list of values of derivatives at the various time points such as $y'[.00017]$ rather than what the derivative actually evaluates to at those time steps.

How do I get the actual value of the derivative rather than these expressions? Note that this needs to be done while NDSolveValue runs. I know I can get these values after the fact using the solution to the differential equation.

Comment: You might also consider the `MonitorMethod` of the [plug-in framework](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolvePlugIns.html)

Comment: Any feedback on my second answer?

Comment: @MichaelE2 I ended up answering the question I was trying to answer with this technique by taking a different approach, so I have to admit this fell to the wayside (it took me a bit to remember why I made this question in the first place). However, I do recognize I shouldn't leave questions/those who answer my questions hanging without feedback. When I have the time I will review your second answer in my system.

Comment: You ask a question, you don't explain a topic.

Comment: @user64494 What?

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to increase the order of your ODE:

```
Reap[
    NDSolveValue[
        {
        y''[x] == -1, (* obtained by differentiating y'[x] == -x *)
        y[0] == 1,
        y'[0] == 0
        },
        y[x],
        {x, 0, 100},
        StepMonitor :> Sow[y'[x]]
    ]
] //Last
```

> {{-0.000145152, -0.000290305, -1.45181, -2.90334, -4.35486, -14.3549, 
>   -24.3549, -34.3549, -44.3549, -54.3549, -64.3549, -74.3549, -84.3549, 
>   -92.1774, -100.}}

Another possibility is to include an additional dependent variable (in which case [`NDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDSolveValue) uses a DAE solver):

```
Reap[
    NDSolveValue[
        {
        y'[x] == z[x] == -x,
        y[0] == 1
        },
        y,
        {x, 0, 100},
        StepMonitor :> Sow[y'[x]]
    ]
] //Last
```

> {{-0.0001, -0.0002, -0.00040102, -0.000711913, -0.001024, -0.00164782, 
>   -0.00227173, -0.00351954, -0.00601518, -0.0110064, -0.020989, -0.040954, 
>   -0.0808842, -0.160744, -0.320465, -0.639906, -0.959347, -1.59823, -2.87599, 
>   -5.43152, -10.5426, -20.5426, -30.5426, -40.5426, -50.5426, -60.5426, 
>   -70.5426, -80.5426, -90.5426, -100.}}

Comment: Adding more variables/equations will be harder/unreasonable for my actual application of this unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Breaking down `NDSolveValue` into its component steps and inserting a hook back to the numerical function that computes the derivative:

```
({state} = 
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y'[x] == -x, y[0] == 1}, 
    y[x], {x, 0, 100}, StepMonitor :> Sow[First@nf[x, {y[x]}]]];
  nf = state@"NumericalFunction";
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, 100];
  y[x] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]) // Reap
(*
  InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 100.}}, <<4>>][x],

  {{-0.000171081, -0.000342162, -0.000684323, -0.00102648, \
    -0.00136865, -0.00479026, -0.00821188, -0.0116335, -0.0458497, \
    -0.0800658, -0.114282, -0.456444, -0.798605, -1.14077, -4.56238, \
    -7.984, -11.4056, -21.4056, -31.4056, -41.4056, -51.4056, -61.4056, \
    -71.4056, -81.4056, -90.7028, -100.}}}
*)
```

---

Remark: `First@nf[x, {y[x]}]` returns the first element of the derivative vector, which is of the form `{y'[x]}` in this case.  For higher order equations and higher dimensional systems, omitting `First` will give the derivatives of all the variables.  Here's an example that uses the built-in utilities described in the tutorial [Components and Data Structures](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveStateData.html) to construct a step monitor that does not depend on how `NDSolve` orders the values in the derivative vector.  It returns substitution rules that may be used to get whichever derivative values are desired.

```
({state} = 
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y''[x] == -x, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0}, 
    y[x], {x, 0, 100},
    StepMonitor :> Sow[Thread[
       NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "X'"] ->
        nf[
         NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "T"],
         Through[
          NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "X"]@
           NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "T"]
          ]
         ]]]];
  nf = state@"NumericalFunction";
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, 100];
  y[x] /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]) // Reap // Last
(* omit "// Last" to get solution and derivative values
  {{{y' -> -2.06958*10^-8, y''] -> -0.00014386},
    {y' -> -6.20874*10^-8, y'' -> -0.000287721},
    ...
    {y' -> -5000., y'' -> -100.}}}
*)
```

Or to get just `y''[x]` and `z''[x]`, in that order, from a system of second-order equations:

```
Clear[state, nf, ypp, zpp];
({state} = 
   NDSolve`ProcessEquations[{y''[x] == -x, y[0] == 1, y'[0] == 0, 
     z''[x] == -y[x] - 10, z[0] == 0, z'[0] == 0},
    {y[x], z[x]}, {x, 0, 100},
    StepMonitor :> Sow[Extract[  (* extract second derivatives from nf[] *)
       nf[
        NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "T"],
        Through[
         NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "X"]@
          NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "T"]
         ]],
       Join[ypp, zpp]]]];
  ypp = Position[NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "X'"], y''];
  zpp = Position[NDSolve`SolutionDataComponent[state@"Variables", "X'"], z''];
  nf = state@"NumericalFunction";
  NDSolve`Iterate[state, 100];
  {y[x], z[x]} /. NDSolve`ProcessSolutions[state]) // Reap
```